# Real time update front end data comming from laravel

Tags: laravel, websocket, push-notification, web-frontend

**Orriginal question**
I'm relatively new to PHP web development and Laravel and looking for a good way to  update my front end data real time. I'm developing a simple web based game what can be played with multiple players. When a player did his turn, the data in all players front end need to be updated.

I know there are 2 ways to do this

1. **Websocket(s)**:
   Laravel does not support websockets by default what means i need to use a third party service like socket IO. As i just want to run my application on a "normal" web hosting, this is not an option.
2. **push messages**:I can also use push message with a service like Pusher or firebase but this option has restrictions when using a free account OR i need to pay after i need more than x resources. This is not what i prefer.

Is there a way to update the front end data without using 3rd party services OR installing a 3rd party application on the server?

---

Serparated from the previous question, i'm curious if push messages (and the eventually suggested solution) works also for mobile browsers.

---

**Question update:**
After the comment of Yeeooow i noticed that i needed to ask the question different. Maybe i need to explain my "problem" a bit more and ask for the solution for this.

In my game a player decides when his turn ends and he can trade a card with other players. In both cases the data need to be updated for all players. I use Vue for the front end and Laravel for backend. What is the best practice to achieve my needs?

Comment: For a real time game, you'll want to use web sockets.  Laravel has broadcasting support built in and there is even Laravel Echo that has the Javascript to support this.  To say Laravel doesn't support this is invalid.

Comment: There is no way to not use the 3rd party when speaking of real-time application also Laravel support with real-time update probably you can check here..
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-socketio-redis-with-laravel-echo

Comment: You say "update my front end data real time" but your game sounds (inferred) turn based.  Why not just use ajax or maybe look into using Vue.  No need to over complicate things and both these options would work on shared hosting.

Comment: @Yeeooow , I'm already using vue for the front end but how can i notify the other users when player x has finished his turn? There is also an "trade card" function in the game, also in this case a player need to be notified. I thought "real time" was the best option here... I'am open for all solutions so also for yours

Comment: @RoDo - I point to the real time issue because you want the information in real-time but the games sounds turn based and some were thinking (again inferred) the game itself is real-time (like an FPS, small but important difference).  I would approach it like this, think of the game as a record in a DB (most likely is that or a set of data points) - when its a persons turn the record is locked to them upon completion of their turn its is locked to the next person etc. etc. re Card Trading - this would be the same idea but on a different table and locked to the user that can initiate a trade etc

Answer (score 0):

you can use websockets with laravel like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)
i had used it with laravel, but you can't use it on shared hosting because you need to import ZMQ and open some ports and that's is not available on shared hosting it is available on VPS or dedicated hosting